# Double or triple....exponent

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Dato l'insieme non vuoto $A$ allora $(A^{c})^{c}$ è uguale a:
\end{document}
```

with this output where we see that the exponents are at different heights,

[image]

> How do I get exponents smaller and smaller that follow an imaginary red line diagonally?

[image]

or with rounded bracket on A^c.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[ A^{c^{c}} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg Hi. But is there a chance to do it even if it is wrong?

Comment: This seems to mean the complement. In this case it could make sense to use `{(A^c)}^c`, but the second exponent should not be smaller.

Comment: @egreg I don't know if the second exponent should be the same. Even if my idea is wrong I would be glad to have an answer.

Comment: I struggle to understand the question. After the first MWE you write "_where we see that the exponents are at different heights_", but the snapshot clearly shows that they are at the _same_ height. In the last edit you write "_with rounded bracket_" but I see no rounded brackets whatsoever. Mi arrendo... `:-)` I've got no idea what you want...

Comment: @campa Dear campa. In the first image the heights are the same and I don't want them. I inserted a second image to make it clear that I want the diagonal exponents. In the last MWE I showed that you can put the exponents diagonally but I am not able to put the round brackets on A^c while maintaining the diagonality of the exponents. :-) very nice for your italian language `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

One of

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Dato l'insieme non vuoto $A$ allora ${(A^{c})}^{c}$ è uguale a:

Dato l'insieme non vuoto $A$ allora ${(A^{c})}^{\scriptscriptstyle c}$ è uguale a:
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer but I wanted the exponents of gradually smaller and smaller size as if they were going diagonally.+1

Comment: @Sebastiano that's the second one, just not as steep diagonal as you showed (it would be steeper in display math, inline  math is trying to keep it in the baseline space so flattens the slope)

Answer (score 5):

Only for the fun of it (ConTeXt, not LaTeX, sorry):

```
\def\mathscalefactor{0.707}

\startTEXpage[offset=3BP]
\im{A^{c^{c^{\setmscale{-} c^{\setmscale{-} c}}}}}

\im{A^{c^{ \dorecurse{20}{c^\bgroup\setmscale{-} } \dorecurse{20}{\egroup} } } }
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: Power towers]

Here the `\mathscalefactor` sets the scale to be used for `\setmscale{-}`, and `\setmscale{-}` really rescales everything in math.

Comment: I don't understand anything about ConTeXt but I thank you so much.